# how to check running application's buildpack In cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, buildpack

How to check running application's buildpack In cloudfoundry?

I have many buildpacks deployed, is it possible to check used buildpacks on running application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent released cloud foundry, it is showing buid packs beside your application.

Answer (score 5):

Two|Three Stepped Process worked for **Cloud Foundry api version: [2.141.0](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/12.1.0/)**:

1. Retrieve the GUID of the application using `cf app <app_name> --guid` - [API Doc](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/app.html)
2. Get App summary using above GUID `cf curl /v2/apps/:APP-GUID/summary` - [API Doc](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/12.1.0/apps/get_app_summary.html)
3. Search for `"buildpack"` in result, should be there - something like this [image]

If `"buildpack"` not found then [follow instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69805569/452708) post from @Smile - Adding here for easier read.

4. Search for `"detected_buildpack_guid"` in above result, e.g. [image]
5. Retrieve Buildpack information using above GUID `cf curl /v2/buildpacks/:guid` - [API Doc](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/12.1.0/buildpacks/retrieve_a_particular_buildpack.html), then search for `filename` in results, e.g., [image]

**Note:** Make sure to **login into Cloud Foundry from terminal** before executing these commands.

Comment: This is the best answer. The previous accepted answer is a good start.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it multiple ways..

You can install `buildpack-usage` cf cli plugin. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ECSTeam/buildpack-usage) or [here](https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/)

The other option is to do 

   `$> cf curl "/v2/apps"`

Check out [Cloud Foundry API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/250/)

Give it a try. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for the up vote! You don't mind, please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Abhijeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58946802/1776132), in case you get `buildpack` attribute as null or empty, you can get the buildpack guid from `detected_buildpack_guid` attribute and call buildback API like

`cf curl /v2/buildpacks/:BUILDPACK-GUID`

Answer (score 0):

This can be fetched from the below V3 APIs.

1. Get the list of Application GUIDs:

   ```
   cf curl '/v3/apps'
   ```
2. Get the relevant buildpacks and its version:

   ```
   cf curl /v3/apps/AppGUID/droplets/current
   ```